# Finding $P(X^2<YZ)$

Tags: probability

Given that $X,Y,Z$ are iid $Unif(0,1)$, compute $P(X^2<YZ)$.

I can only get this to $P(X<\sqrt{YZ})$ since they're all non-negative. How would I go from here? Do I need the triple joint distribution? (with one being the square of unif(0,1))?

Comment: This has already been asked several times. The shortest way: for every $x$ in $(0,1)$, $P(X<x)=x$, and $\sqrt{YZ}$ is in $(0,1)$ almost surely, hence $P(X<\sqrt{YZ})=E(\sqrt{YZ})=E(\sqrt X)^2=\ldots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if, indeed, the shortest way is the one suggested by Did in a comment, yet, I would go through the elementary steps.

$$P(X<\sqrt{YZ})=\int_0^1\int_0^1P(X<\sqrt{YZ}\mid Y=y,Z=z)\ dy\ dz=\int_0^1\int_0^1P(X<\sqrt{yz})\ dydz$$

because of independence.

So,
$$P(X<\sqrt{YZ})=\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{yz}\ dydz$$
because $X$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1$].

Finally,

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\sqrt{yz}\ dydz=\int_0^1\sqrt y\ dy\int_0^1\sqrt z\ dz=\frac 49.$$

because $$\int_0^1 y^{\frac12}\ dy =\frac1{1+\frac12}=\frac23$$

Comment: for the first equality, in the integrand, should there be the density $f_{Y,Z}(y,z)$?

Comment: Yes. I omitted that step: $f_{Y,Z}(y,z)=1$ over $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Comment: So for questions like this, where we have some inequality with $n$ random variables,, you'd have to condition it on some $n-1$ r.v.s and proceed from there?

Comment: Yes, if it makes sense. Most of the time it does.

Comment: @zoli Surely the final result is $4/9$ not $9/4$?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'll correct.